# Can i use two quotations with Array()?

Tags: php, arrays, translation

I translate my website to French, i would like to know if this is correct

```
$lang = array(

"tittle" => "C'est bien",
"desc" => "Bienvenue sur mon site",
);
```

If i use:

```
'tittle' => 'c'est bien',
```

i get an error.

Comment: Look at the text highlighting in the question; you're using single quotes both to delimit the string, and inside the string itself.

Comment: or you can escape the quotes with a backslash, so `'car' => 'my \' car'` or `'car' => "my \" car"` (not the best example i know)

Comment: The biggest argument for escaping is it you need to represent a string that contains both ' and ". Best to learn it love it because it will be on the test.

Comment: Yes, i tryed 'tittle' => 'C\'est bien', humm it's working, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to say that you can't mix the string delimiters as is convenient

```
$lang = array(
    'tittle' => "C'est bien",
    'desc' => 'Bienvenue sur mon site',
);
```

Personally, I use single quotes around most simple strings, but would rather use double quotes in a case like this rather than escape.  To me it some seems more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use one quote type for denoting the bounds of the string literal and another type for inner literal values. Mixing them both won't work, as the string needs a beginning and an end, and it couldn't be determined otherwise (omitting escaping as a possibility, which only leaves code yet more unreadable.)

Comment: @Femaref Yes, as I noted, I can't think why anyone would seriously consider that a good idea.

Comment: Why not? It's not like you'll have long strings in your code anyway.

Comment: @Femaref Length is rather irrelevant, even `'c\'est bien'` is an eyesore and unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "escape"... `'tittle' => 'c\'est bien'`

PHP has a function for do that: http://php.net/addslashes

Comment: Seriously, what's the point? This just makes it even more ugly and harder to read/maintain.

Comment: Yes, it's very ugly :/

Comment: escaping is a necessary evil... imagine you needed to represent `<a href="#" onclick="alert('you just click me');">Click Me</a>` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) within [doubles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) or doubles within single quotes, but if you try to put singles within singles or doubles within doubles you have to escape. For example, the following would have to be escaped:

```
$str = 'c\'est bien';
$str = "John said, \"We should go.\"";
```

However, you can do either of the following without escaping:

```
$str = "c'est bien";
$str = 'John said, "We should go."';
```

One advantage with using double quotes is that you can use variable and various escaped characters:

```
$str = "Welcome $name, to our site!";//variable within string
$str = "Break this string for a new line.\n";//new line character
$str = "\tThis line begins with a tab";//tab character
```

With single quotes, escaped characters are treated as literals, and variables have to be concatenated:

```
$str = 'Welcome '.$name.', to our site!';//variable concatenated in string
echo '\tNo tab here.';//prints out: \tNo tab here.
```

Comment: you are trying to say that, this way is correct ? i mean inside Array()
$lang = array(

"tittle" => "C'est bien",
);

Comment: @Mafitsi - Yes, that's fine.